# Link generation

Tags: java, web

I'm developing a web site for voting and now I encountered a problem. I need to generate a link to my vote and send it by email. (It's some kind of varification) It's the same system as we receive a letter from a site to confirm our registration. Are there easy ways to do that? Are there any tools for that. I have an idea neither how to store such links in the database, nor how to send them to users. I hope you understood what I meant. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to generate a random text and append it as parameter to your link.

Before you send the link to the user, save your random key associated with your action and user in your server/database etc. Remmeber to make it a unique value/PK.

For Java there is `UUID.randomUUID()` but there are other ways.

Something like: `<your_url>?token=66bfa5a0-db96-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66`

You can enhance this suggestiong with expiration time, encryption, etc.

**UPDATE 1 - SMTP/send emails**

The only protocol that I know of for sending e-mails is SMTP (besides the Microsft proprietary ones).

Most common library for Java is [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). There are other libraries too, but JavaMail is very simple and will do the job.

You should try this tutorial [JavaMail API - Sending Email Via Gmail SMTP](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/), it is very simple. You will use Gmail service to send an e-mail for you. It is safe dont worry.

When you finish testing with Gmail you can connect to your local E-mail server and do the same, just change the parameters to connect with it, and remove the TLS/SSL parameters if not supported.

If your local server do not support TLS/SSL you can google other examples on the internet. They will be actually simpler because there are less configuration.

As for your solution about the votes, the best way is to send a **HTML** e-mail. So the link for the vote will be in the HTML message. It will be the same as when you receive e-mails with images ans links.

[How to send an HTML email in Java](http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/how-to-send-html-email-in-java-using.html) will give you an idea and also demonstrates Apache Commons Email too, that requires less code.

Comment: I want that a vote creator could write email into the email list and then just press send. I want links to be automatically delivered. I know how to use my email in a standart way, but I don't know how to send letters by my email with java?

Comment: @Max updated with HTML emails and SMTP protocols.